# Como colocar o cursor do mouse em uma posição especifica de um campo de texto?

Tags: python, gtk

Estou tentando formatar um campo do tipo `entry` do gtk que estou utilizando para a entrada de datas e queria adicionar o caractere `/` em determinadas posições confirme o usuário vai digitando..

E a única coisa que está faltando é posicionar o cursor do mouse para a ultima posição da string quando eu adiciono o caractere `/`.. Tentei usar o método `set_position()` mas aparentemente não funcionou.

Comment: Você pode perguntar em português aqui Gustavo, bem vindo.

Comment: haha @re22 valeu, vou mudar a pergunta!

Comment: Cursor do mouse ou cursor do texto? Note que são coisas diferentes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passei pelo mesmo problema, e usei o seguinte:

```
campo.set_position(-1)
```

Para facilitar fiz um exemplo, onde o cursor do texto irá sempre para o fim.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject

class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        self.entry = Gtk.Entry()
        self.entry.connect('changed', self.set_cursor)
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.add(self.entry)
        self.show_all()
        self.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)

    def set_cursor(self, widget):
        widget.handler_block_by_func(self.set_cursor) # bloqueia o sinal da entry
        GObject.idle_add(self.entry.set_position, -1) # cursor do texto no final do campo
        widget.handler_unblock_by_func(self.set_cursor) # desbloqueia o sinal da entry


Window()
Gtk.main()
```